# jPlayer - set to play once and only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jplayer

I've been searching for the best way to get a jPlayer instance to allow an audio file to only be played once.  I think I could call `.jPlayer("destroy");` after the event is completed, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(id).jPlayer( "clearMedia" ) : jQuery
```

You can use this to clear your current media after playing one song. After that play button wont play anything untill you use new url by using `setmedia` method

Comment: Thanks! I used that code and tied it to the `$.jPlayer.event.ended` Event Type: `$("#id").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(event) {
   $("#id").jPlayer("clearMedia");
 });`